# How to get node asset_builder working with current express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, express

I've been trying to use the `asset_builder` node module with express 3.1, but can't seem to make it very far in the setup before receiving an error like this upon starting the server:

```
var parsed_url = url.parse(request.url);                      
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

This is being thrown from within the `middleware.js` file of the asset_builder module itself. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that Express apps no longer extend server, and so the setup in the base (`app.js`) file is a bit different than it once was.

Ideally I'm just trying to use asset_builder to grab all my javascript and serve it as a single file rather than the many I currently have (Ember app).

The base project I'm working off of uses `ejs` as the express view engine (instead of the default `Jade`).

Comment: There are other issues with `asset_builder` as well that will prevent it from working with Express 3 (like the use of `app.locals.use(function() ...)`).

Comment: @robertklep I suppose the more reasonable question would then be "What node asset builder/manager can I use that works with Express 3"?

Comment: I can't recommend any because of lack of experience, but I know a lot of people use Grunt, and there's also [asset-pipeline](https://github.com/rlidwka/asset-pipeline) which looks pretty similar to asset_builder.

Comment: @robertklep Interesting to note that the github readme for asset_builder states that it requires Express 3.x.

Comment: perhaps the GH master has Express 3 support (worth giving it a try), but the version in the NPM registry clearly doesn't. The example code in the README also shows Express 2 code.